# SQL Storage in OpenVBX (Twilio)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, twilio

I'm writing a [plugin for openVBX](http://www.openvbx.org/docs/api/2010-06-01/plugin/).

I need to store some stuff in a table I made in the OpenVBX database.

OpenVBX Provides a helper method ([PluginData::sqlQuery](http://www.openvbx.org/docs/api/2010-06-01/plugin/data/plugin-data/)) to run queries but no way to escape them, so I decided to open a new PDO connection in my plugin page, but I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/plugins/QPage/qpage.php:119
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/plugins/QPage/qpage.php(119):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/OpenVBX/views/page/index.php(7):
>   include_once('/home/elitecall...') #2
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/system/libraries/Loader.php(677):
>   include('/home/elitecall...') #3
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/system/libraries/Loader.php(307):
>   CI_Loader->_ci_load(Array) #4
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/OpenVBX/libraries/Template.php(388):
>   CI_Loader->view('page/index', Array, true) #5
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/OpenVBX/libraries/MY_Controller.php(455):
>   CI_Template->write_view('content', 'page/index', Array) #6
>   /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/OpenVBX/libraries/MY_Controller.php(498):
>   MY_Controller->template_respond('Phone Apps', 'page/index', Array, 'yu
>   in /home/elitecallcenter/public_html/ivr/plugins/QPage/qpage.php on
>   line 119

Line 119 is my execute call for a prepared statement.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was written in codeigniter, so I'm reading up on that to figure out the best way to do this. In the mean time, I've got a functioning workaround set up that involves making a cURL request to another script in the base directory that is able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

How large / heavy is the query? Generally you get MySQL server has gone away as a timeout.

You could try raising 'wait_timeout' in my.cnf to something more suitable or try raising 'max_allowed_packet' to '128M'.